# Convert timestamp column from UTC to EST in spark scala

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, jodatime, utc

I have a column in spark dataframe of timestamp type with date format like '2019-06-13T11:39:10.244Z'
My goal is to convert this column into EST time(subtracting 4 hours) keeping the same format.
I tried it using from_utc_timestamp api but it seems it is converting the UTC time to my local timezone (+5:30) and adding it to the timestamp then subtracting 4 hours from it. I tried to use Joda time but for some reason it is adding 33 days to the EST time

innput = 2019-06-13T11:39:10.244Z

using from_utc_timestamp api:

```
val tDf = df.withColumn("newTimeCol", to_utc_timestamp(col("timeCol"), "America/New_York"))
```

output = 2019-06-13T13:09:10.244Z+5:30

using Joda time package:

```
   val coder : (String => String) = (arg: String) => {
     new DateTime(arg, DateTimeZone.UTC).minusHours(4).toString("yyyy-mm-dd'T'HH:mm:s.SS'Z'")}
   val sqlfunc = udf(coder)
   val tDf = df.withColumn("newTime", sqlfunc(col("_c20")))
```

output = 2019-39-13T07:39:10.244Z

desired output = 2019-06-13T07:39:10.244Z

Kindly advise how should I proceed. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a typo in your format string when creating the output.

Your format string should be yyyy-**MM**-dd'T'HH:mm:s.SS'Z' but it is yyyy-**mm**-dd'T'HH:mm:s.SS'Z'.

`mm` is the format char for minutes while `MM` is the format char for the months. You can check all format chars [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html).